# Bridging Swift & Objective-C protocols?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, swift

Bridging Swift to Objective-C is *very* painful so far.
The compiler is unforgiving about all types including integer types.
For example if you were sloppy and declared something as an (int) instead of an (NSInteger), you'll get a compile error that the function is just not found.

Example: I have this existing Objective-C protocol declared in a `PixelMapUI.h` header:

```
@protocol DeleteKeyDelegate <NSTableViewDelegate>
- ( void ) deleteKeyPressed: ( NSTableView * ) view onRow: ( int ) rowIndex;
@end
```

And in my new Swift class, I'm trying to do this:

```
extension NSTableView {

override func keyDown( event : NSEvent ) {
  var obj : NSTableViewDelegate = delegate()
  var obj2 = obj as? DeleteKeyDelegate;

  let characters : NSString = event.characters;
  var firstChar = Int(characters.characterAtIndex( 0 ));
  // if the user pressed delete and the delegate supports deleteKeyPressed
  if ( ( firstChar == NSDeleteFunctionKey ||
        firstChar == NSDeleteCharFunctionKey ||
        firstChar == NSDeleteCharacter) )
  {
     if let keyObj = obj as? DeleteKeyDelegate {
         keyObj.deleteKeyPressed( self, onRow: selectedRow() );
     }
  }
```

}

This produces a compiler error:

> "Could not find member 'deleteKeyPressed'

After stumbling around, I finally changed my Objective-C protocol from (int) to (NSInteger) and it started working.

** sigh ** if Swift is going to be as unforgiving as Java, it's not going to be pretty code when every other line of code has a typecast integer.
Is there some option to have Swift not treat integer type mismatches as errors?

Comment: well 'int' is not 'NSInteger' and a lot of crazy bugs can occur when you don't distinguish both. Remember Ariane 5 explosion :)
Using swift is a great way to make sure you don't assert the size of your numbers and avoid your code to break when you go from one architecture to another. Can be annoying when you come from a loosely typed language but you'll soon love it :)

Comment: Agree with @StephanePhilipakis. The whole point of Swift is to make absolutely sure at compile time that there are no errors in your code. And `int` is not guaranteed to be the same as an `NSInteger` and if you mixed them in your C or Objective C code, that __is__ an error. An error that the compiler does not catch. Your code may or may not work. It may work now, and stop working when the user upgrades to the next version of the OS. With C and ObjectiveC you will only see the error when it happens at runtime (maybe in the future). With Swift you see it when you compile the code today.

Comment: See http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6397357142835200

Comment: One problem is that the swift compiler is not helpful when it tells you that an objc method does not exist.  It does exist, its just that the type is slightly different.  The compiler needs to point out the reason for the error, especially for mismatched numeric types.  Type safety for numeric types is important some of the time.  My worry is that people who try to port c-code to swift will introduce bugs.  Swift forces you to typecast every other line of code, making code unreadable.  Worse yet, porters will try to change working objc code, introducing bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This one compiles and works quite fine.
I know theres a "magic constant" in there ;-) (51 -> Backspace), but for demonstration only the if statement is relevant ;-)

```
@objc protocol MyTableViewDelegate {
    func deleteKeyPressed(row:Int)
}

extension NSTableView {
    override public func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) {
        if let ds = self.delegate() as? MyTableViewDelegate {
            if theEvent.keyCode==51 {
                ds.deleteKeyPressed(self.selectedRow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```